# Getting a console error while trying to migrate a Vue App with VueRouter

Tags: javascript, java, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am tying to port a stand alone Vue app into a larger Java Spring web project. The Vue app has Vue router as a dependency. When I try to load the main page, I am getting a `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'to' of undefined". found in ---> <RouterLink>...<AppHeader> at src/views/AppHeader.vue` error in the browser console.

The main JSP loads fine, and is using a compiled JS file.

**src/main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import AppLayout from './views/Layout.vue';
import router from './router';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import vueMoment from 'vue-moment';
import VueTippy from 'vue-tippy';
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(AppLayout)
});
Vue.use(VueTippy);
Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(vueMoment);
```

**src/views/AppLayout.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
   <app-header></app-header>
    <section class="main-section section">
      <div class="container content">
        <router-view></router-view>
      </div>
    </section>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import AppHeader from './AppHeader.vue';
import AppFooter from './AppFooter.vue';
export default {
  components: {
    'app-header': AppHeader,
    'app-footer': AppFooter
  }
}
</script>
```

**src/router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import SearchForm from '../views/search/searchform.vue'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  scrollBehavior: (to, from, savedPosition) => ({ y: 0 }),
  routes: [
    { path: '/app/path/search', component: SearchForm },
    { path: '/app/path/new', component: NewReturn },
    { path: '/app/path/home', component: SearchForm },
    { path: '/', redirect: '/app/path/search' },
    { path: '*', component: NotFound }
  ]
})
export default router
```

**src/views/Appheader.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-link to="/app/path" exact><a href="">Search</a></router-link>
  </div>
</template>
```

It seems like router-link is not working for some reason. I can't seem to figure out how to fix this issue. Anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an `<a>` tag inside the router-link, that is rendered by vue when using `<router-link>`

https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link

The undefined 'to' will be your empty href declaration.